# material design lite sidenav onhide show icons only

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

I am trying to make a sidenav that when toggle, it will not fully hide the sidenav and will show icons representing each tab.

My code is here..

```css
header .mdl-layout__drawer {
  border-right: 0;
}
header .mdl-layout__drawer .mdl-layout-title {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
header .search input {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
header .search label {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
header .user_img {
  border-radius: 24px;
  width: 40px;
}

.sidenav {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right: 0;
}
.sidenav .mdl-layout-title {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13725) 0px 2px 2px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 3px 1px -2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11765) 0px 1px 5px 0px;
}
.sidenav .mdl-navigation__link.active {
  color: #2196F3;
}
.sidenav .mdl-navigation__link span {
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.mdl-layout__content {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.account_action .inner {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.account_action .inner .material-icon {
  color: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.2.1/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.blue-light_blue.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header mdl-layout--fixed-drawer mdl-layout--fixed-header has-drawer">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield search">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search">Search</label>
      </div>
      </span>
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <!-- Right aligned menu below button -->
      <button id="demo-menu-lower-right" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
        <i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>
      </button>

      <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="demo-menu-lower-right">
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Another Action</li>
        <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
      </ul>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/326334/profile/profile-80_2.jpg" alt="user_image" class="user_img"/>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer sidenav">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title mdl-color--blue-500 mdl-color-text--blue-grey-50">Title</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">dashboard</i><span>DASHBOARD</span></a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">description</i><span>FORMS</span></a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link active" href=""><i class="material-icons">account_box</i><span>MY ACCOUNT</span></a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="mdl-grid account_action">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"><div class="inner"><i class="material-icons">person_add</i></div></div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"><div class="inner"><i class="material-icons">group_add</i></div></div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"><div class="inner"><i class="material-icons">color_lens</i></div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
```

QUESTION: i want the sidenav to be like the sidenav in the given image which is a sidenav that is not fully hide and will show the icon representation each link.

is it possible to do this approach on material design sidenav?

[image]

full link of the image...
https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html

Comment: @Dejan.S question edited. kindly check.

Comment: I think the problem here is your code is using a slide over the top sidebar, but you want one that squishes the page.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it only as editing CSS. This is just a sample. You can get an idea how to edit CSS after you see this sample. 
[Here is a sample.](http://jsbin.com/hogehaqavi/1/edit?html,css,output) To see you need to click the button 'run with JS'