# Show only icons when sidenav is closed in shinymaterial

Tags: r, shiny, material-ui, materialize

I am using shinymaterial and the corresponding materialize.css file to customise an app. I wanted to show icons only when the sidenav is closed. I have read a few posts related to material design lite but am not familiar with this and the differences (if any). However, still can't make it work. If anyone has implemented this in shinymaterial apps, any help much appreciated. If this can be done in css that would be great too.

Comment: I would suggest adding what you've tried so far along with any expected/unexpected results.

Comment: I tried to follow this post and respective comments/suggestions but no luck... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977213/material-design-lite-sidenav-onhide-show-icons-only

Comment: I would also suggest the same as @Y.S., with the desired output (for instance the img one can see on the SO you mentionned)